# Weak 2-coloring of a graph but one color is stong?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

Given a planar graph how can I color its vertices with 2 colors, A and B, given that:

1. Color A cannot have a neighbor of color A and should have 1 or more neighbors of color B
2. Color B can have any number of neighbors of color B and should have 1 or more neighbors of color A

Anybody knows the name of an algorithm for such coloring or the name of a coloring like this or a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given such a coloring, the vertices of color A form an [independent dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Domination_by_independent_sets), and conversely, given an independent dominating set, you can color its vertices with color A and the rest of the vertices with color B to get a suitable coloring. This is assuming that the graph contains no isolated vertices, but this is clearly necessary for the existence of such a coloring.

If you just want to find *any* such coloring, you can greedily take a maximal independent set; this will give you an independent dominating set. Finding the smallest independent dominating set appears to be NP-hard, even for planar graphs. As for concrete bounds, Theorem 5.1. in [this survey](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/%7Egoddard/papers/idomSurvey.pdf) gives an algorithm that, given a $k$-coloring (in the usual sense!) of the graph, finds an indepent dominating set of size $(k−1)n/k−(k−2)$. Practically, this gives you an independent dominating set of size $4n/5 - 3$, since there are fast algorithms for finding a five-coloring of a planar graph (while finding a four-coloring is difficult at this point).

Comment: Thank you, definitely helpful! Another thing is that every vertex has degree 4 or can be converted to have degree 3. I think I need the largest independent set, which indeed is NP-hard. I will try to take the positions of the vertices in 3d space also into account when trying to solve this problem.